# How to get correct color component including alpha value of pixel of QImage?

Tags: qt

Color have `(0,127,0,100)` value of rgba component and we mark this color in `QImage` and read the red color of pixel of `QImage` it gives different value i.e it gives red component =50.

code

```
    m_color(QColor(0,127,0,100); 
    m_pen.setColor(m_color); //set Qpen color
    m_painter.setPen(m_pen);
    m_painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source); 
    painter->drawPixmap(Qpoint(0,0),*m_Pixmap);//m_Pixmap is QPixmap
    m_painter.drawline(initialpoint,finalpoint);// draw line over transparent pixmap item
    QImage img =m_Pixmap->toImage;

    for (int i=0;i<img.height();i++) //col
    {
        for(int j=0;j<img.width();j++) //row
        {
            qDebug()<<qGreen(img.pixel(j,i));  /// it return 50 during traverse painter line else give 0/// but it should return 127 as red component is 127
     ///code
            }
            if(QColor(img.pixel(j,i)==m_color)/// its never true// it should true during traverse the line draw by painter on pixmap
                   ///code
            }
        }
    }
```

nothing is set to painter it directly draw line... and colored matching is true when  m_color have color without alpha value or if alpha is 255

Comment: Where do you ever use `m_pen`?  Also note that if any anti-aliasing is active for the painter then that will have a effect on the actual colours written.

Comment: to what object painter is attached? Last line suggest that it is a `img`. If so: how did you initialized this `img` (assuming that it is a `QImage`)? Why you are sure that `i, j` points to part of image where you are expecting proper color you've used to draw a line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: i changed the code , now it is minimal and complete and can reproduce problem

Answer (score 0):

According to the Qt4 documentation m_Pixmap->toImage will return a RGB32 Image without an Alpha channel. Dataformat is 0xFFRRGGBB. So Alpha will be always 255.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#toImage

Try preserve the QImage when you convert your image to a QPixmap.